# Why does this print?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a text based game in Python. I made a dictionary of rooms.

[image: Room_dictionary]

afterwards I created a variable called starting_room. I then assigned starting room to 'Meadow'...

```
starting_room = rooms['Meadow']
```

Then I run the program and it printed off the dictionary of starting room without me initiating a print statement.

```
output: {'East': 'Town'}
```

My question is; why did it print? As well as why the dictionary and not just the word meadow?

I apologize if this is a dupe question.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please do not share code as a picture, we can't replicate without painfully transcribing your picture into code. Please edit and paste your code. You can use the little `{}` button at the top of the editor to preserve formatting as I've done with your two lines of code in your question. Please also share any relevant code here. The fact that it printed sounds dubious. Share enough that we can replicate the issue you are facing.

Comment: It is because the value of the key "Meadow" is a dictionary, and that dictionary happens to be ```{'East': 'Town'}```. When you do ```rooms['Meadow']``` you are accessing the value associated with the key "Meadow"

Comment: @RichardKYu Assignment in and of itself shouldn't output anything to stdout.

Comment: @Axe319 Oh ok, I missed this part about not having the print. OP, I think you should include all the code you are using for us.

Comment: Are you using IPython? Some interactive notebooks like Jupiter will automatically print newly assigned variables. I wouldn't recommend developing a game in IPython.

Comment: @JNevill thanks for editing. I noticed my sleight errors. Also, I shared the code as a picture because I've stated I had a dictionary with the contents. I figured we've all seen it before, and a simple two key dictionary will do the same. There is no error in my code. It is not an issue. Just a genuine question since I am trying to learn. Eli I'm sorry but that is out of my vocabulary. Could you specify what you mean? Richard thank you, that explains a lot.

Comment: Rooms = {‘Meadow’: {‘East’: ‘Town’}, ‘Town’: {‘North’: ‘Forest’, ‘West’: ‘Meadow’, ‘East: ‘Mountain’, ‘South’: ‘Desert’}, ‘Mountain’:{‘North’: ‘Volcano’, ‘West’: ‘Town’}, ‘Cave’:{‘West’: ‘Forest’}, ‘Desert’:{‘North’: ‘Town’, ‘East’: ‘Ravine’}, ‘Forest’: {‘South’: ‘Town’, ‘East’: ‘Cave’}, ‘Ravine’: {‘West’: ‘Desert’}, ‘Volcano’: {‘South’: ‘Mountain’}} starting_room = ['Meadow']                  I then ran the program and it output the dictionary of meadow.

Comment: I am using pycharm @Timor

Comment: @oCosmic Eli is asking you to share the exact code you ran as text. That way we can copy  and paste it into our IDE and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Axe319 oh okay, I gave it all my code. I am confused as to how I received an output from my code. When I didn't initiate any print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dictionary is a key value store, by using starting_room = rooms['Meadow'] you are accessing the values for key 'Meadow',
if you want to print the key then you can refer to below link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-key-from-value-in-dictionary/

Comment: Thank you! This is actually what I was trying to do to begin with, but was curious as to why it printed the value instead of the key. Thank you!

Comment: Also, what if I did not want it to print anything? I was just trying to assign start_room with Meadow. Expecting no output. I then ran the code after I assigned meadow to start room. That's where the question comes as, why did it print anything?

Comment: Python wont print an assignment unless you are using Ipython.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "rooms" contains a dictionary (key, value pairs). So, by assigning "rooms['Meadow']" to "starting_room" all you're doing is picking the value that the key 'Meadow' has i.e., {'East': 'Town'}.

If you want the whole dictionary and its key, values, you can try:

```
for key, value in rooms:
    print(f"{key} -> {value}")
```

Comment: Thank you, I am more or less trying to assign a new variable called starting_room and trying to assign the room 'Meadow' to it. I ran the program just to see what it would do. Expecting nothing to be printed and it ended up printing the following as stated.